# ZF2 good practise of extending users

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I am working on a module that should extend a users profile.
In this case i have a Curriculum vitae module, and i need to find a to do the coupling to the user.
What I'm asking is what is the right way to do this, to keep good practise, also when i delete users (cleanup)?

Comment: this question is too broad. The answer depends very much on your needs, there is no black and white answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not entirely black and white. and I'm sorry for that.

For being able to extend a user profile depending on the active modules on the system i came up with a normal loose connection between the modules by using controller plugin.
this controller plugin is using a service factory to access the user object.
Then I'm able to access they users information from any other module.

Then when i need to connect a address module or maybe a curriculum vitae to a existing user, I'm able to do so by calling the controller plugin, and asking for the user ID, and then do the storing using a service factory

same goes when i want to get info then I'm just asking the eg. service factory for address to give me the address, if I'm logged in it will return my address else i can parse the parameter of one of the unique keys of the user and then get the specific user.